# look in readP Haskell Parser why doesn't it return a value

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to get a better intution of the `readP` [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html) :

Why does this:

```
pLookIf :: Parser String 
pLookIf = (do
        looked <- look --munch isDigit
        e1 <- munch isDigit
        if looked == e1 then return ( "(" ++ e1 ++ ")" )
        else return "88"
        return looked
        )

parseString input = readP_to_S (do                         
                        e <- pLookIf
                        eof
                        return e) input
```

return:

```
ghci> parseString "8888888888888"
[("8888888888888","")]
```

When this

```
pLook :: Parser String 
pLook = (do
        looked <- look
        return looked
        )

parseString input = readP_to_S (do                         
                        e <- pLook
                        eof
                        return e) input
```

Returns:

```
ghci> parseString "8888888888888"
[]
```

In both cases some value should be returned, considering the signature: `look :: ReadP String`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Look-ahead: returns the part of the input that is left, without consuming it.

So, we `look` at the rest of the input.  Then we try `eof`, but since we haven't consumed anything we are not at the end of the input and `eof` fails, so there are no successful parses.

In `pLookIf` we have `munch isDigit` which consumes the rest of the input, so we are at the end and `eof` succeeds.

To fix `pLook` you either need to add something similar to parse up to the end, or just test without the `eof` until you have a parser that works on the whole input.